# [KAFKA][GRAYLOG] Direct Buffer OOM

Tags: memory, apache-kafka, graylog2, graylog

I have a simple setup with several producers writing to one kafka with multiple topics. My one and only consumer is Graylog instance writing to ES. After a week or two of activity kafka started to throw:

```
[2017-10-03 13:17:56,018] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:694)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
        at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:241)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:195)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.read(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:153)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:286)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:413)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-10-03 13:17:56,530] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:694)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
        at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:241)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:195)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.read(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:153)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:286)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:413)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Everything seems to work fine so far but I expect this kafka will go down soom. Is there anything I can do with this?

Graylog machine: 10 GB RAM, 6 CPU 2,7 MHz 
server JVM:

```
\_ /usr/bin/java -Xms5g -Xmx5g -XX:NewRatio=1 -server -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///etc/graylog/server/log4j2.xml -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/graylog-server/lib/sigar -Dgraylog2.installation_source=rpm /usr/share/graylog-server/graylog.jar server -f /etc/graylog/server/server.conf -np
```

kafka zookeeper:

```
java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/data/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/data/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./../config/log4j.properties -cp :/data/kafka/bin/../libs/* org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /data/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

kafka:

```
java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/data/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/data/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./../config/log4j.properties -cp :/data/kafka/bin/../libs/* kafka.Kafka /data/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Memory stats on Kafka/Graylog machine:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9831        7337         133           6        2360        2130
Swap:          2047        2047           0
```

3xElasticsearch: 10GB RAM, 8 CPU 2,7 MHz

```
/bin/java -Xms5g -Xmx5g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.4.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

Comment: What are the hardware specs of the machine running Graylog?
What are the JVM options for the Graylog and Elasticsearch processes?

Comment: updated description

Comment: Since Kafka threw the `OutOfMemoryError`, you should try giving it more memory or run it on a system with sufficient memory.
Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html (`-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`).

Comment: From docs:
Sets the maximum total size (in bytes) of the New I/O (the java.nio package) direct-buffer allocations. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. By default, the size is set to 0, meaning that the JVM chooses the size for NIO direct-buffer allocations **automatically**.

Is automatic wrong or not working at all??

Comment: Looks like there is sufficient memory on this host.

Comment: "Is automatic wrong or not working at all?" – It obviously doesn't work for you, does it?